# Convert ~500mb csv file to adjacency list

Tags: csv, mapreduce, adjacency-list, large-data

I data scraped from Kickstarter.com. The format of data is in CSV with headers "backer" and "backed_projects". The "backer" column stores all the profile urls of backers and the "backed_projects" column stores a list of projects that the backers have backed. The list is separated by semi-colons. I want to make a network diagram in Gephi to see if there are clusters of backers who tend to back the same projects. In the graph, if two backers have backed the same project, they would be connected by an edge. The input format for the data would have to be backer and the backers who have backed the same project(s).

I'm not sure how to process the original large CSV file to the format backer -> list of backers who have backed the same project(s). Any suggestions?

Anyone know an efficient way to use map reduce?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think gawk can necessarily handle this 500mb, but you can accomplish the same thing in most languages( java, perl etc ).  I'm also assuming that just listing the edges is fine w/o recompiling them into a single line.

I'll assume an input file ( "input" ) like this( where the urls are names now ):

```
joe;proj2,proj9,pro8
erin;proj1,proj7,pro8
sue;proj47,pro7
elmo;pro7
```

run the following:

```
cat input | gawk -F"," '{
    split( $1, arr, ";" );
    printf( "%s;%s\n", arr[1], arr[2] );
    for( i = 2; i <= NF; i++ ) { printf( "%s;%s\n", arr[1], $i ); }
}'
```

which produces the following output:

```
joe;proj2
joe;proj9
joe;pro8
erin;proj1
erin;proj7
erin;pro8
sue;proj47
sue;pro7
elmo;pro7
```

These appear to be edges according to [gephi csv-formats](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/csv-format/)

Or you could further process the output.

What I don't remember is whether or now awk/gawk consume the whole file up front.  If the output's alright then processing each line into multiples would work in many other languages.

---

Okay - while I still think my first attempt is more useful, here's a 2nd version where everything is slightly rewritten and includes a new gawk to make a dot file digraph output( which lets me check it out in Yed - see comment ).

"input" file like ( typos in first attempt dropped the "j" in "proj" ):

```
joe;proj2,proj9,proj8
erin;proj1,proj7,proj8
sue;proj47,proj7
elmo;proj7
```

make an executable file out of the following ( I'll call it "explode" ):

```
gawk -F"," '
{
count = split( $1, sc, ";" ); 
printf( "%s %s\n", sc[2], sc[1] ); 
for( i = 2; i <= NF; i++ ) { printf( "%s %s\n", $i, sc[1] ); }
}
'
```

which changes the output or the original gawk because it's going to be used for sorting/feeding the next gawk script (another executable file; I called this one "combine" ):

```
gawk -F" " '
BEGIN { printf( "digraph similar_users (\n" );
    project_name = "";
    users = "";
    }

{
if( $1 ~ project_name )
    build_users_string( $2 );
else {
    make_user_nodes( users );
    users = "";
    build_users_string( $2 );
    }
project_name = $1
}

function build_users_string( u )
{
    users = sprintf( "%s%s%s", users, length( users ) == 0 ? "" : " ", u );
}

function make_user_nodes( u )
{
    if( (count = split( u, arr, " " )) <= 1 )
        return 1;
    for( i = 1; i <= count; i++ )
        {
        printf( "%s -> ", arr[ i ] );
        for( j = 1; j <= count; j++ )
            if( j != i )
                {
                end = (i == count ) ? count-1 : count;
                printf( "%s%s", arr[j], j != end ? "," : ";\n" );
                }
        }
    return( count );
}

END { make_user_nodes( users );
    printf( ")\n" );
    }
'
```

which reads a sorted input file from the "explode" script and when run as follows:

```
cat input | explode | sort | combine > output.dot
```

produces the file "output.dot" where "user -> list of users who were associated with the same project"

```
digraph similar_users (
elmo -> erin,sue;
erin -> elmo,sue;
sue -> elmo,erin;
erin -> joe;
joe -> erin;
)
```

The memory used should only be as bad as the sort and the largest project/user conversion in the last script because it only processes the users grouped by project whenever the project name changes.  A more memory intensive "single pass" would put all users in a map of proj -> ( list of users ) and do all the processing of the map at the end.  Notice that users pointing to a single project are dropped.

Comment: This outputs node -> edge, but the gephi csv-format is node -> node(which is treated as an edge).

Comment: Okay - so I don't know the inputs to gephi :), but I can edit this script to output a .dot language file that can be converted to .graphml using [dottoxml](http://www.mydarc.de/dl9obn/programming/python/dottoxml/) and [Yed](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) where the output is treated as node->node.  I guess my question is why are you asking for a solution that throws out the projects.  Following this example - do you really want joe->erin; erin->joe; sue->elmo; elmo->sue, with users pointing to one project left out?

Comment: I want the graph to be user to user because I want to show clusters of users who often back the same projects. Thanks!

Comment: If you want the user list/cluster to be inclusive of the user on the left, you can replace the i/j loops with `sub_count = gsub( " ", ",", u );
        for( i = 1; i <= count; i++ )
            {
            printf( "%s -> %s;\n", arr[ i ], u );
            }` in the maker_user_nodes() functions in the edit.